# Automation Anywhere File Trigger failure

Tags: rpa, automationanywhere

I set a file trigger for my robot, but it does not function. 
Concretely speaking, if a person puts a file (any file) in the assigned folder, 
the robot is supposed to start working. 
However, the robot is not working. 
This happens frequently. 
For now, to fix it, restart PC is needed.

In case you know what is happening to my dear robot,

### please tell me how to fix the issue.

ADD:
We have a runner to run 4 robots, all of them are triggered by creating new files.
3 trigger files are located in server A and the left 1 trigger is located in another server B.
During the error, all triggers in server A didnt work and no record left in evenwatcher. But the trigger in another server worked well with correct record in eventwatcher.

We have checked server setting, no error happend and no firewall settings which might cut the connection.

Comment: What version of AA do you have? Is a background process AutomationEventWatcher.exe running?

Comment: Thank you so much for asking. The version is 10.5.0, and I am sure Event Watcher is working. To be exact, I have two robots, one of which are triggered when a file is created in Folder A, and the other robot is triggered when a file is created in Folder B. However, a file trigger in Folder A is functioned and recorded in Event Watcher, whereas a file trigger in Folder B is NOT functioned and NOT recorded in Event Watcher....

Comment: You are saying "This happens frequently" does that mean it works once in a while?

Comment: Thank you very much for asking. Yes, it works for a while. If the problem above happens, it keeps not funtioning untill restart PC.

Comment: AS restarting PC is solving prblem, it means problem is with EventWatcher.exe. It should be running all time with available CPU and RAM. Please check EventWatcher process.